# Which are the top 10 most important verbs to learn in German?

Tags: verb

I'd like to focus on that at first and then continue to incorporate more...I'm self studying using various resources from the internet(youtube, tv shows, bilingüal books, whatever comes at hand)...

For now I have learned these and incorporated them quite good:

```
verstehen
gehen 
lieben 
mögen 
essen 
schwimmen 
bezahlen 
fahren 
sein 
trinken 
sprechen
schlafen
```

What other verbs do you recommend?

Comment: These kind of questions are more likely to attract opinion-based answers, which don't really fit into the SE model. Please consider checking our [help] and reading [ask] and what is on-topic to learn more about how this site works. I think you should in first place learn the two auxiliary verbs *sein* and *haben* which are similiar to the french *être* and *avoir* or spanish *ser* and *estar*.

Comment: Brauchen (to need) is another,  in my opinion,  important verb

Comment: @Juan, I edited your question and wrote all of your verbs in the infinitive form (present time +en)

Comment: Two equal verbs which are commonly used are *machen* and *tun* (to do), but as stated it's my opinion @Iris Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Iris, except for “möchten” ;)

Comment: @CarstenS, wie peinlich ^^

Comment: thanks to all, It's hard to start out and this is the beggining of a great journey....I'm going to germany in two weeks...

Comment: @Juan, I wish you a wonderful time in Germany!